# Parallel Interpreter For "Treehugger" Programming Language Not Functioning As Intended

Tags: java, interpreter

[Treehugger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger) is a variant of the infamous Brainf*** programming language that, instead of running on a tape, runs on a binary tree that is infinite downwards. For [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51273/output-every-halting-program-write-a-parallel-interpreter) on the Programming Puzzles and Code Golf stack exchange, I'm attempting to write a Parallel interpreter for it that will eventually output every syntactically valid, halting program in the language, excluding those which require input and those that produce output.

For some reason, it also seems to omit all non-empty programs shorter than about 5 characters while also including some with blatantly invalid syntax. Of course, these are problems that need to be fixed before I can start golfing it.

Here's the source for it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class I{
    static class NODE{
        public NODE l=null,r=null;
        public byte v=0;
    }
    static class PROGRAM extends Stack<NODE>{
        public int i=0;
        public char[]s;
        public boolean h=false;
    }
    static void step(PROGRAM t){
        if(t.i>=t.s.length){
            t.h=true;return ;
        }
        char c=t.s[t.i];
        if(c=='<'){if(t.peek().l==null)t.peek().l=new NODE();t.push(t.peek().l);}
        if(c=='>'){if(t.peek().r==null)t.peek().r=new NODE();t.push(t.peek().r);}
        if(c=='^')t.pop();
        if(c=='+')t.peek().v++;
        if(c=='-')t.peek().v--;
        if(c=='['&&t.i==0){
            int i=1;
            while(i>0){
                t.i++;
                if(t.s[t.i]==']')i--;
                if(t.s[t.i]=='[')i++;
            }
            return;
        }
        if(c==']'&&t.i!=0){
            int i=1;
            while(i>0){
                t.i--;
                if(t.s[t.i]==']')i++;
                if(t.s[t.i]=='[')i--;
            }
            return ;
        }
        t.i++;
    }
    static char[]n(char[]a){
        String b="<^>+-[]";
        for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            int j=b.indexOf(a[i]);
            if(j<6){a[i]=b.charAt(j+1);return a;}
            a[i]='<';
        }
        char[]c=Arrays.copyOf(a,a.length+1);
        c[a.length]='<';
        return c;
    }
    public static void main(String[]a){
        List<PROGRAM>programs=new ArrayList<PROGRAM>();
        char[]c={};
        while(true){
            PROGRAM t=new PROGRAM();
            t.s=c;
            if(isBalanced(c))programs.add(t);
            c=n(c);
            for(PROGRAM u:programs){
                try{step(u);if(u.h){programs.remove(u);System.out.println(String.valueOf(u.s));break ;}}catch(Exception e){
                    programs.remove(u);break ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static boolean isBalanced(char[]c) {
        int i=0;
        for(char d:c){
            if(d=='[')i++;
            if(d==']')i--;
            if(i<0)return false;
        }
        return i==0;
    }
}
```

So where exactly is the problem in this? I can't seem to find it, but, based on the output, it's obviously there somewhere.

Edit: I was able to find the problem on my own. What should I do with this question now?

Comment: Leave the question as it is, it could be helpful for other users too.

Comment: `output every syntactically valid, halting program in the language,` That is a nondeterministic task, it cant be solved / finished within the lifespan of this universe. Sorry, you failed before you even began.

Comment: The idea is to generate one at a time the possible programs in the turing-complete language being interpreted and, while doing so, interpret in parralel those which are syntactically valid. Then, print them to the output as they halt, excluding those which triggered an exception. Every valid, cleanly halting program will eventually appear in the output exactly once, though it may take an arbitrarily long time for it to appear. And yes, I know it will never actually finish.